# fail initialization backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model class. I have an initialize function. If I want to not initialize the class/object on invalid data, what do I do?

```
initialize: function (data) { 
  if (!valid(data)) { 
     // don't initialize and return an object
  }
}
```

Comment: You say _view_ in the title and _model_ in the description, which is it?

Answer (score -1):

you need to override constructor in this case

```
var Library = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function (attrs) { 
    if (!valid(attrs)) {
      return {anything: 'else'}; 
    }
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

---

Please keep in mind, that:

- such model may not work inside Backbone collection
- if you want to support full Model validation flow - use Emile answer
- And most important: *Please use this only if you know what are you doing*

Comment: Don't override the `constructor` like that, you'll break the model you're expecting when doing `new Library()`. And it'll break any Backbone collection using that model class.

Comment: @EmileBergeron It will work as expected. Have you tried this?

Comment: It won't throw an error, but it's bad practice in this case.

Comment: @EmileBergeron There are many ways to hell... but when somebody asks how to get to hell - i will just show the road. The question was exactly about that.

Comment: That's not the spirit of stack overflow.

Comment: @EmileBergeron you don't know how this will be used, we even don't know exact question :-) I agree that there are negative sides, you need to agree that this solution will work for certain cases :-)

Comment: @EmileBergeron edited my answer. Does it look better now?

Answer (score -1):

A model already has a validation mechanic built-in. You may first define a [`validate` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) on the model.

> This method is left undefined and you're encouraged to override it
>   with any custom validation logic you have that can be performed in
>   JavaScript. By default `save` checks **validate** before setting any
>   attributes but you may also tell set to validate the new attributes by
>   passing `{validate: true}` as an option.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> var Chapter = Backbone.Model.extend({
>   validate: function(attrs, options) {
>     if (attrs.end < attrs.start) {
>       return "can't end before it starts";
>     }
>   }
> });
> ```

Then, you have the handy [`isValid` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid) to check if the model is in a valid state.

```
initialize: function (data) { 
  if (!this.isValid(data)) return; // early return
  // normal initialization here
}
```

The return value of `initialize` is ignore. If you want to change the attributes back to a default when invalid, you can just do so with `set`.

```
initialize: function (data) { 
  if (!this.isValid(data)) {
    this.set({ defaultValue: "test" });
    return;
  }
  // normal initialization here
}
```

Comment: @AndreyMuzalevsky it's still ambiguous and looks like a typo from OP. It makes more sense with a model than with a view (as written in the description).

Comment: @AndreyMuzalevsky A model also has a `initialize` function, which receives `data` as a first argument and `options` as the second, versus the view's `initialize` where `options` is the only default param.

Answer (score -1):

Backbone Model will always run any `initialize` function upon instantiating object, if you don't want something to be executed don't put it on the `initialize` function.
You can also throw an error and handle it.
Cheers.